# Colorizing and swapping colors with PHP GD Image Library?

Tags: php, image, gd, imagefilter

Hello I am in the process of trying to colorize and swap colors on an image using GD image library with PHP.

I am using an original image located here:
http://korlon.com/youknowbetter/test.jpg

And wish to get it to a point where it is orange face with black clothes and hair much like you see here:  http://youknowdifferent.org/

So far I've used the following code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');



imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 255);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 252, 137, 36);


imagejpeg($im);
?>
```

To get it close but I am still missing the ability to turn all the white shades to black shades.
http://korlon.com/youknowbetter/filter.php

I have tried swapping out white for black as instructed in this question here:
[Can I swap colors in image using GD library in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456044/can-i-swap-colors-in-image-using-gd-library-in-php)

However that doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't actually swap out the colors.  Is that because I am using a jpg and not a gif?  Is there something I need to do with the color palette?

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

STOOB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Blue (#0276DB) instead of orange, and then inverse the image (using `IMAGE_FILTER_NEGATE`) to get orange and black.

So, your code will be:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');



imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, 255);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 2, 118, 219);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);

imagejpeg($im);
?>
```