# How to process a vintage/retro filter on image by API

Tags: php, javascript, image

I am trying to apply image filtering to images, like retro/vintage/B&W, etc.

Is there any ready-to-use libraries implementing image filtering that I could use? My app will be a web-app so maybe a PHP or javascript lib/API ?

I already ran into http://pixlr.com/ but they just give the opportunity to use their image editor, and no image processing script that could be automated. Geez!

Thanks for your answers ;)

Comment: Related: [Colorizing and swapping colors with PHP GD Image Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/717686)

Comment: And more - what you need may already be there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+image+filter+

Comment: Thanks Pekka! Yes I know that pho image filters do exist, what I need is a bunch of filters in a library that I can use. I dont want to program them from scratch...

Comment: Should the image processing happen server- or clientside?

Answer (score 0):

http://camanjs.com is a js lib that can manipulate image on client side