# PHP/GD change the color of a simple black/dark gray PNG to another solid color

Tags: php, gd

I have images like these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiOfh.jpg

And I want them to end up like the first of the image here (with the second image being the result of the code I made):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap1ZJ.jpg

I tried:

```
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -250);
```

I also tried adding the brightness filter, changing the contrast filter around - but it never gets perfect.

I tried to change all the black to blue, but since the image is made of some grays, it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456044/can-i-swap-colors-in-image-using-gd-library-in-php

Comment: The problem with these is that the black is not 0,0,0 black - it's a lot of lighter gray which need to be converted not to straight red, but a equally lighter red as the black was light black. If this makes sense.